# API tests : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: json, api, json.net, nunit

So I am learning C# and api tests. I have some tests running but they have now stopped working completely with the below error. Nothing has changed. Any ideas? Completely stuck. Tried cleaning solution and rebuilding. It just stopped working

Message:
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Stack Trace:
Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) Task`1.get_Result()
ComponentTests.WhenARequestIsMadeToCreateTheTodoItem() line 57
ComponentTests.CanCreateTodoItem() line 37
--HttpRequestException
ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
--SocketException
ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

````
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using TodoApi.Models;

namespace TodoApi.Tests
{
    public class ComponentTests
    {
        private HttpClient client;
        private TodoItem todoItem;
        private HttpResponseMessage response;
        //private APIItems deserializedString;

        public ComponentTests()
        {
            this.client = new HttpClient();
        }





        [Test]
        public void CanCreateTodoItem()
        {
            string[] Names = {"Walk dog"};

            foreach (string nameValue in Names)
            {
                GivenATodoItem(nameValue);
                WhenARequestIsMadeToCreateTheTodoItem();
                ThenResponseStatusCodeIs(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            }
        }

        private void GivenATodoItem(string nameValue)
        {
                this.todoItem = new TodoItem
                {
                    Id = "g24c34a7-68d0-4f46-b3fe-9aa75127387a",
                    Name = nameValue,
                    IsComplete = true
                };
            
        }

        private void WhenARequestIsMadeToCreateTheTodoItem()
        {


            response = this.client.PostAsync(
                "https://localhost:44387/api/todoitems",
                new StringContent(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(todoItem),
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json")).Result;

        }

        private void ThenResponseStatusCodeIs(HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode)
        {
            Assert.That(this.response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(expectedStatusCode));
            Console.WriteLine(this.response.StatusCode + " Matches expected " + expectedStatusCode);
        }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access an API using Blazor and Visual Studio? In this case, you simply need to change the StartUp Project default from SINGLE to MULTIPLE.  Right click on your Solution, Properties, StartUp Project THEN make sure to include your API project as 'STARTUP' together with your default.